# Colored noise and adjusting covariance matrix with change of frequency

Tags: frequency-spectrum, noise, kalman-filters, covariance

Assume a signal sampled at 2Hz.
Assume it is a colored noise with known PSD.
The measurement equation to be used in a Kalman filter requires a covariance matrix.
If I want to sample at 9Hz (for example), how should I modify the covariance matrix?